# split and create tree from Bd

Tags: java

I have a SQL table with following structure for example

```
name     father
-----------------
alex     kmal jury salama
```

I have tried with this code ...but it does not work

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/bd/Base8.accdb");
java.sql.Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
ResultSet result= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name,father FROM Base1");
     while(result.next())          
       splitword(result.getString("father"),result.getString("name"));  
       Node.print(root);




public static void  splitword(String father,String son) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(father.split(" ") ));
    Collections.reverse(result);
    result.add(son);
    System.out.println(result);


    root2=new Node(result.get(0));
    result.remove(0);

    CreateTree(result,root2);


}
private static void CreateTree(ArrayList<String> result,Node tree) {
      if(result!=null) {
          Node  child=new Node(result.get(0));
          System.out.println(result.get(0));
          result.remove(0);
          tree.addChild(child);
          CreateTree(result,child);  
      }
```

My class Node:

```
public class Node {
        private String data;
        private Node parent;
        private List<Node> children;


        public Node(String data) {
            this.data = data;
            parent = null;
            children = new ArrayList<Node>(); //Empty list of children  
        }
```

how can create this tree represented below

```
          salama
           |
          jury
           |
          kmal
           |
          alex
```

salama is father of jury and jury father of kmal and like this...
it s just an example for implement a big tree 
thank u

Comment: what does data mean, did you mean the name of the person ?

Comment: data ,yes the name of person

Comment: check my edit hope this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this hope that help you

```
private static void createTree(ArrayList<String> result, Node tree) {
    if (result != null && !resultat.isEmpty()) {
        Node child = new Node(result.get(0));
        tree.addChild(child);

        createTree(result.subList(1, result.size()), child);  
    }
```

Comment: What is this doing? Can you explain the code? What did you change?

Comment: 1-You need a stop condition for a recursion, to avoid it being infinite and you have one: if (result! = Null) You could extend it to test also if the list is empty, otherwise you risk an IndexOutOfBoundException .                         2-result.remove(0);---it can cause problems in the rest of the code, because you modify the list. One could easily get away without taking out the first node, passing a list that does not contain the first node to the recursive call. And we can do that easily with sublist:

Comment: Nice, please **edit** your answer and include this information there, thanks.